# Get mean of a single variable with dplyr

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, mean

I'm using the diamonds dataset and I'm trying to find the mean price for each of the cuts.
I thought this would work

```
diamonds_data %>%
  filter(Cut == 'Ideal') %>%
  mean(Price)
```

But I get the following warning message:

```
[1] NA
Warning message:
In mean.default(., diamonds_data, Price) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
```

Comment: Are you planning to compute the mean prices one by one or are you interested in having the mean prices of all cuts?

Comment: I'm going to want to select each of them one at a time for a shiny app, so I think one at a time would be good.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot use `mean` as a function on a dataframe. If you want to get a numeric value starting from a column, use `pull` to extract that column from the dataframe.

```
diamonds_data %>% 
  filter(Cut == "Ideal") %>% 
  pull(Price) %>% 
  mean()
# [1] 3457.542
```

Comment: How to remove NA values?

Answer (score 1):

To simply make your code work, try `mean(.$price)`.

```
diamonds %>%
  filter(cut == 'Ideal') %>%
  {mean(.$price)}

# [1] 3457.542
```

A better choice is computing the mean price for each `cut` all at once, and assign the summary table to an object.

```
price <- diamonds %>%
  group_by(cut) %>%
  summarise(mean_price = mean(price))

# # A tibble: 5 x 2
#   cut       mean_price
#   <ord>          <dbl>
# 1 Fair           4359.
# 2 Good           3929.
# 3 Very Good      3982.
# 4 Premium        4584.
# 5 Ideal          3458.
```

When you need some value, extract it from the table.

```
price$mean_price[price$cut == "Ideal"]

# [1] 3457.542
```